# How to create 4d array with random data using numpy random

Tags: python, numpy, tritonserver

My model accepts data in the shape(1, 32, 32, 3), I am looking for a way to pass the data using np.array from numpy. Any help on this will be appreciated please

Comment: What is the shape of your input data ?

Comment: `np.random.rand(1, 32, 32, 3)`

Comment: @rochard4u my shape of the input data is shape": [1, 32, 32, 3] and datatype is fp32

Comment: Thanks @GodIsOne, How can I add it to numpy.array ?

Comment: @Mahesh just assign it to a variable. It will be your numpy array. `arr=np.random.rand(1, 32, 32, 3)`. So now `arr` is your numpy array with shape `(1, 32, 32, 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data right now is a one-dimensional array you want to convert your input data to a 4-dimensional array? Because a 4d array is a matrice of matrices the data input you have right now looks like a singular index within a matrix of the bigger matrix of matrixes. to create a 4d array it just:

```
a = np.random.rand(1, 32, 32, 3)
```

to get something better we need the structure of your data